# The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files while deploying to github in wndows

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I am trying to publish to gh-pages using yarn on windows 10. this is my script:

"scripts": {
  "gh-pages":  "gh-pages --dist . --src '{index.html,dist/**,CNAME}'"
 }

and i have a CNAME file in my root directory. now when i run this script (in dev branch)

npm run gh-pages

I get this error:

> The pattern in the "src" property didn't match any files.

It works fine on linux but has error on windows? what should i change here?

Comment: `"scripts": { "gh-pages": "gh-pages --dist . --src '[index.html,dist/**,CNAME]'" }` ?

Comment: @Popmedic nope. still same error!